# Only logged in on some pages - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I am not aware of the cause to the problem myself, so I know that you don't have much to go on. But thought I would ask here, because I really cannot figure out why wordpress is acting like it is.

The problem is that when you log in, then at first everything seams fine, you get redirected to a my-account page. But if you then go to the front page, you are not shown as logged in anymore, sometimes it helps refreshing the site, and sometimes it does not. If you then go back to another page then it says that 
you're logged in. So this only occurs on some pages.

The same problem occurs on another site, where members can download an e-book. and if you're not a member then there is a register form so you can become a member and then download the e-book. But the problem is that when people are logged in, then they still cannot download the book, because that site does not detect them as logged in.

I do suspect that it has to do with the cache, as we have had several problems with that. But have no idea of how to fix this one.

**We need to send this e-book out today, and it is really important, so all help would be really appreciated!**

Comment: what caching plugin(s) are you using?

Comment: @TudorConstantin I am not the one who made the site to start with. Just working on it now for a company that I am in. I checked the plugins and the only thing I can find that has to do with cache is a plugin named "W3 Total Cache"

Answer (score 2):

It seems that others had the same [logged out issue with W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/logged-in-members-are-server-cached-pages-from-not-logged-in-users)

From the thread, some potential solutions:

1. Visit yoursite's `wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_pgcache#general` , and check the option "Don't cache pages for logged in users".
2. In `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_browsercache#html_xml` , if *Set cache control header* is checked, please make sure that the *Cache Control policy:* is not one of the following:

> ```
> Cache
> Cache with max-age
> ```

Also, it'd help, if *Set expires header* option is unchecked as well. If checked, the browsers are likely to cache the content for logged-in users as well, after seeing the expires header.

If the above are not working, try to:

3. check *Set cache control header* under `html/xml`then chose *cache with validation* in the scroll down menu.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this and then come with some feedback

Comment: I see that the Cache Control policy is in fact set to: Catche with max-age("public, max-age=EXPIRES_SECONDS") 
What should it be set to instead then?